# Sidebar + Fixed Top Menu in Semantic-UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is it possible to have a Sidebar + Fixed Top Menu in Semantic-UI React?

Answer (score 4):

have you tried something like this ?

```
<!-- Top fixed menu -->
<Menu fixed="top">
    <Button className="item" onClick={this.toggleVisible}>
      <i className="sidebar icon" />
    </Button>
   <Menu.Item name="home" as={Link} to="/your_route">
      <Icon name="home" />Menu item
   </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
 <!-- Sidebar & pusher -->
<Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
   <!-- Sidebar menu -->
   <Sidebar
    visible={this.state.visible}
    as={Menu}
    animation="push"
    width="thin"
    icon="labeled"
    vertical
    inverted
  >
    <Menu.Item name="home" as={Link} to="/your_route">
      <Icon name="home" />Sidebar menu item
    </Menu.Item>
  </Sidebar>
  <!-- pusher container -->
  <Sidebar.Pusher>
    <Segment basic>Whatever content</Segment>
  </Sidebar.Pusher>
</Sidebar.Pushable>
```

You must implement toggleVisible function to toggle sidebar visible state.